# UINavigationItem doesn't show up

Tags: uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

In IB I've put an View Controller with a Table View and a Navigation bar. Because I want to change the actions (and text) on the buttons when the table is being edited, I decided to create the button programatically.
In the implementation file, I've set up the button (copied from another post on Stackoverflow):
`- (void)viewDidLoad {`
`[super viewDidLoad];`
`self.title = @"Title";`
`UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)];`
`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;`
`}`

But when I run this in the simulator, I don't see the button. Is this the right approach for my goal? Or what am I doing wrong? 
Later, I also want to add a `Back`, `Add` and `Done` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did not created iboutlet for that navigation bar. Self.navigationItem is a property which is available on any viewcontroller and is applied only if there is a navigationcontroller which manages your viewcontrollers stack. There is no relation to manually created navigationItems..

I assume that either outlet for that navigationbar or going to storyboard, click your viewcontroller and then Editor->Embed In->navigation controller will help you to achieve disered results.